# How do i use smarty and pear on xampp in mac?

Tags: php, macos, apache, smarty, pear

How do I use smarty and pear on xampp on mac?

I tried to use Smarty.
But doesn't work there, I changed the permission of the templates_c file.
It worked! Then I installed pear! It didn't work!
I tried to change the permission pear in file!
It didn't work!
Why? Please tell me. It is as follows.

> Warning:
>   require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/DB/DB.php): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/smarty.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB.php'
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/PEAR.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/smarty/libs.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/DB')
>   in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/smarty.php on line 3

```
<?php

require_once('DB.php');

// load Smarty library
require('Smarty.class.php');


$smarty = new Smarty;

$val2 = $smarty->template_dir = "smarty/templates";
$val3 = $smarty->compile_dir = "smarty/templates_c";

$smarty->assign('name','kinopyo!');
$smarty->display('smarty.tpl');

?>
```

Comment: You may get a better help if move this question to ServerFault, since StackOverflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, but you can try installing modules via Composer for automatic dependency resolution: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md